# Triggers and Actions for Creature AI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

Despite my creature AI working (for the most part), I feel like the way I've set it up is terribly inefficient and likely committing some programming sins. I want to rewrite it to be more clean, efficient, and easier to maintain but I'm not exactly sure where to begin.

In my creature AI, I have a list of triggers, such as OnSpawn, OnDeath, or OnCollisionEnter. Within each trigger is a list of actions such as "Cast a Spell" or "Play an Animation". When a trigger's conditions are met, its list of actions are processed to check if it's not already in our processing list, adds it, and then plays their associated actions. When the trigger's conditions are not met, the list of actions are removed from this process list, and similarly processes through some remove functions to clean up behavior.

Some code that I've simplified:

```
    void Update()
    {
        if (canAct && !dead)
        {
            CheckTriggers();
            PlayAllActions();
       }
     }


   private void CheckTriggers()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < actions.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (actions[i].trigger)
            {
                case ActionTrigger.Trigger.OnCollisionEnter:
                    if (isColliding)
                        AddActionList(actions[i].actionSetList);
                    else
                        RemoveActionList(actions[i].actionSetList);
                    break;

                case ActionTrigger.Trigger.UponBeingAttacked:
                    if (hasBeenAttacked)
                        AddActionList(actions[i].actionSetList);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddActionList(ActionSetList actionSetList)
    {
        bool containsItem = existingActionsList.Any(item => item == actionSetList);
        if (containsItem)
            return;

        existingActionsList.Add(actionSetList);
    }

    private void PlayAllActions()
    {
        if (existingActionsList.Count > 0)
            for (int i = 0; i < existingActionsList.Count; i++)
                ActionPlayEffect(existingActionsList[i]);
    }

    public void ActionPlayEffect(ActionSetList actionSetList)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < actionSetList.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (actionSetList[i].type)
            {
                case ActionSet.Type.CastSpell:
                    if (spellRoutine == null && actionSetList[i].cooldownTimeRemaining <= 0)
                        spellRoutine = StartCoroutine(Cast(actionSetList[i]));
                    break;

                case ActionSet.Type.PlayAnim:
                    if (!isInActionPose)
                    {
                        animator.SetTrigger("ActionTrigger");
                        animator.SetInteger("Action", (int)actionSetList[i].animToPlay+1);
                        isInActionPose = true;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void RemoveActionList(ActionSetList actionSetList)
    {
        bool containsItem = existingActionsList.Any(item => item == actionSetList);
        if (containsItem)
        {
            ActionRemoveEffect(actionSetList);
            existingActionsList.Remove(actionSetList);
        }
    }

    public void ActionRemoveEffect(ActionSetList actionSetList)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < actionSetList.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (actionSetList[i].type)
            {
                case ActionSet.Type.CastSpell:
                    CancelCast();
                    break;

                case ActionSet.Type.PlayAnim:
                    animator.SetTrigger("ActionTrigger");
                    animator.SetInteger("Action", 0);
                    isInActionPose = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

What can I do to build a more efficient creature AI?

Comment: Wit this incomplete (non-functional) example, it's hard to make any suggestions.  What is "more efficient" for you?  What sort of game engine drives this?  This *sounds* like a straightforward event-driven AI running in a cycle-based game, but you haven't detailed the problems well enough.  What isn't working with your current actions queue?  In most applications, the queue processing time is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write a similar system using [delegates](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_delegates.htm).

A delegate can to some extent be considered a variable holding a list of methods. If you execute that delegate you then execute all the methods it holds.

This would allow you to add methods like this, to a list of methods that you then call when desired.

```
delegate void OnSpawn(GameObject gameObject); //Create delegate type
public OnSpawn onSpawn; //Create variable from delegate type

void SetUpStats(Gameobject gameObject){
    //Set hp, initialize spells
}

void SetUpAnimations(GameObject gameObject){
    //Initialize animations
}

void PlaySpawnSound(GameObject gameObject){
    //Play a spawn sound
}

void Start(){
    if (onSpawn == null) //Add content to delegate
    {
        onSpawn = new OnSpawn(SetUpStats); //You may be able to write onSpawn = SetUpStats; instead, for shorter code. But please test it.
        onSpawn += SetUpAnimations;
        onSpawn += PlaySpawnSound;
    }
}

void Spawn(){
    onSpawn(gameObject); 

    //Call delegate, invoking all methods stored in it. 
    //Note that they all receive the same input. In this case the gameObject.
    //You can give them any input you want, so long as you define it in the delegate type.
    //I chose a gameObject as you can get all components and more from it.
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions or things you wonder about.